# Move directories in C:\Windows to D:? (by means of junction point)

Tags: windows-xp, ntfs, junction

Can I move the following directories from `C:\Windows` to `D:`, and
replace them with a junction point?

```
Microsoft.NET
assembly
$hf_mig$
Installer
```

Answer (score -1):

regarding $hf_mig$ you can just simply delete it without worrying. This applies to all $* folders. If you don't plan to uninstall security patches then you do not need those.
If you want to make that junction, just use the junction utility 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx

Comment: Deleting `$hf_mig$` is [not a good idea](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-performance/can-i-delete-updateexe-file-in-cwindowshfmig/fb0e3f9d-80f9-40cf-a4d1-c2dfc9a8862e?msgId=f232c802-e8fe-4c27-9d6f-baee887f3d9b&auth=1). Concerning junctions: I know how to create them, just I am not sure if there are any negative side effects of moving certain directories to `D:` and replacing them with a junction point.

Comment: Well so if you think the described situation applies to you then leave that folder, but it can be half a gig... I am administering hundreds of Windows XP pcs and there was no problem deleting this.
What kind of side effects do you mean? I think that OS should not notice any difference. It works with games and I think it should apply to Windows as well. If there was a problem you can just revert it back. Judging from what you ask I guess you have not enough space on c: right? Maybe besides this you should also try software like CCleaner or SpaceSniffer to see where else you can save space.

Comment: Keeping `$hf_mig$` is necessary since it provides resources that may be needed later when removing and also when *installing* software on Windows. This has been discussed [on Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/337447/why-do-i-need-to-keep-hf-mig).